# std::pair() having empty values with something like boost::optional

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair, boost-optional

```
class LinkStats{
public:
    LinkStats(std::shared_ptr<Configuration> config) {
        m_interface = "eth0";
    };

    ~LinkStats() = default;

    std::pair<int32_t, int32_t> getRxLinkStats() {
        auto status = getLinkStats();
        if(nullptr != status){
            return std::make_pair(status->rx_errors, status->rx_dropped);
        }
    }

    std::pair<int32_t, int32_t> getTxLinkStats(){
        auto status = getLinkStats();
        if(nullptr != status){
            return std::make_pair(status->tx_errors, status->tx_dropped);
        }
    }

private:
    rtnl_link_stats* getLinkStats() {
        getifaddrs(&m_ifaddr);
        m_interfaceAddresses = { m_ifaddr, []( ifaddrs * x ) { freeifaddrs( x );}};
        for ( ifaddrs *ifa = m_interfaceAddresses.get(); ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
            if ((ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET) &&
                (ifa->ifa_data != NULL) &&
                (ifa->ifa_addr != NULL) &&
                (0 == m_interface.compare(ifa->ifa_name))) {

                return static_cast<rtnl_link_stats*>(ifa->ifa_data);
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<ifaddrs, std::function<void(ifaddrs*)>> m_interfaceAddresses;
    ifaddrs *m_ifaddr;
    std::string m_interface;
};
```

I have written the above class to get the link stats, `rx_error`, `rx_dropped`, `tx_error`, `tx_dropped`.

In the two functions above, `getRxLinkStats()` and `getTxLinkStats()`, I want to know if there is a elegant way to return the `std::pair()` that will indicate that it is empty, meaning `getLinkStats()` have failed.

Comment: `std::optional<std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>>`? (Use `boost::optional` if your compiler doesn't support C++17 and [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional))

Comment: Or, if you have some "pinned", exceptional values of int32_t, e.g. std::pair<-1, -1>, then you can use them to indicate an error. Likely it would have a lesser overhead than `optional`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::optional<std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>> getRxLinkStats() {
    if (auto status = getLinkStats())
        return std::make_pair(status->rx_errors, status->rx_dropped);
    }
    return {};
}

std::optional<std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>> getTxLinkStats(){
    if (auto status = getLinkStats()) {
        return std::make_pair(status->tx_errors, status->tx_dropped);
    }
    return {};
}
```

for boost-based (ie, [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)), use `boost::optional` instead of `std::optional`.